# Exception bypassing in Looping call Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, task
from twisted.python import log
def periodic_task():
    log.msg("periodic task running")
    x = 10 / 0

def periodic_task_crashed(reason):
    log.err(reason, "periodic_task broken")

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

my_task = task.LoopingCall(periodic_task)
d = my_task.start(1)
d.addErrback(periodic_task_crashed)
reactor.run()
```

I am getting the output and it stops the script. is ther any way to continue run the script even if there is an exception error . to be frank instead of x = 10 / 0 I am doing some api calls . but when there is an error it stops the script. But what I want is to run the script even if there is an error and check again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle the exeption, use a try ... except block around the code you know might fail.

```
def periodic_task():
    log.msg("periodic task running")
    try:
        x = 10 / 0
    except Exception as error:
        # Here you should at least log the error, exceptions do not should pass silently.
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that the script continues to run, even if there is an error, use a `try / except` block.

Within the `except` block, in order to, as specified in your query, ensure that the code checks the error, again and again, you'd use 'function recursion' to run the function again from within the function:

```
def periodic_task():
    log.msg("periodic task running")
    try:
       x = 10 / 0 # include 'API calls' here
    except: # include 'exception type'
       periodic_task()
```

Although, there are [many pitfalls with function recursion](https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php) so be wary!